# Probability puzzle involving crickets on a chess board

Tags: probability, puzzle

I was given the following problem in a technical interview:

> Suppose you have a normal 8x8 chessboard, and crickets are placed on
>   every single square. The crickets begin to hop from square to square
>   at random. Every cricket hops to every square on the board with equal
>   probability, and there is no limit to how many crickets fit on a
>   single square.
>
> Here is the question: We let them hop for a little bit, and then take
>   a picture of the board. How many squares do we expect to find empty?

At first, I thought this would be easy. The crickets hop completely independent of one another, so it should just be some riff on the regular binomial distribution. When you try to work it out, though, you realize that the events we're logging are *not* independent, since whether a given cricket lands on an empty square depends on where the crickets before him have landed.

Every attempt I make to solve this ends up involving variants of the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). I haven't been able to get a good answer. I'm wondering if anyone sees an obvious solution, or a non-obvious one. I'm also interested in how this problem looks if you start making the chessboard get bigger, up to size infinity.

Comment: Two big hints: (1) there's no dynamicism in this process; you might as well assign each cricket to a random square in the first place.  (2) _Linearity of Expectation_ doesn't depend on independence.  What's the 'expectation' (on a single square) of the function that assigns 1 to that square if it's empty and 0 if there are one or more crickets on it?

Comment: Does "crickets are placed on every single square" mean "1 cricket is placed on each square" (i.e., there are 64 crickets)?

Comment: @HaoYe, there are indeed exactly 64 crickets.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I think you might be onto something. Are you saying that I shouldn't be trying to work out the whole board at once, but rather a single square at a time? In that case, the probability that more than one cricket lands on a given single square is the sum from i=1 to i=64 of (64 choose i) * (1/64)^i * ((64-i) / 64)^(64-i). The expected value of the function you gave is then 1 - that, or (according to the Haskell program I just wrote .55, which would imply an average of 35 empty squares.

Comment: @phoniel You don't need more than one - even exactly one cricket landing on a square is enough for that square to be non-empty.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I should have said "At least one."

Comment: @phoniel you can only assign each cricket to a random square in the first place, if sufficient time has passed for every cricket to have jumped at least once.  This is perhaps implied by the question but not explicitly stated. As such, the question can't be answered for definite as stated in my answer below. Near to the outset, the crickets will of course be evenly distributed but as soon as the 64th cricket has jumped at least once, the best estimator is given by my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this precisely a binomial distribution, because we have 64 crickets and place each randomly on one of 64 squares?  (The starting arrangement and the intermediate hops are irrelevant.)  The probability is thus $0.364987$.

Comment: You should be explicit that this is the probability for one square to be empty (and hence the expected fraction of empty squares). Also, it's nice to note that this is $(1-1/64)^{64} \approx 1/e \approx .368$

Comment: This is not the probability for exactly one square on the board to be empty. Rather, it is the probability that, for a given square, crickets do not end up on that square.

Comment: @phoniel Right, that's what I meant, though your wording is clearer: it's the probability for a given square to be empty.

Comment: By the linearity of expectation, this is the expected fraction of unoccupied squares.  The answer to the question as asked is then $64 \cdot 0.364987 \approx 23.36$

Comment: @RossMillikan In a binomial distribution the probability of every square being empty is non-zero, yet it is zero in in this case. This is because the outcomes on any two squares in this problem have none-zero covariance arising out of the fact that a cricket not on one square must be on another square.  See my answer below.

Comment: @RobertFrost:  yes, they are correlated, but the linearity of expectation doesn't care about that.

Comment: @RossMillikan so by your binomial model, what is the probability that all 64 squares are empty?  I'll look at your other comment in due course.

Comment: It isn't specifically a binomial model-you are correct that not all squares can be empty.  The calculation of the probability that a particular square is empty is correct.  We can then calculate the expected number of empty squares, but that doesn't tell us what the probability of any given number of empty squares is.

Comment: @RossMillikan OK I'll fix my answer to make it perfect.  It's going to be later tonight probably.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the large number of grasshoppers (trials) and low probability of a grasshopper being placed on a square (1/64), I would use poisson probability  to model the number of grasshoppers on one square

we have lamda = (1/64) and 64 'trials' so the probability of zero is given by

e^-lamda (lamda^x) / x!

therefore

e^-1 = .37..

so 37% empty

---

by the way, if you look at @aes comment below. for infinite chessboard with infinite grasshoppers, his formula (1 - 1/64)^64 tends to (1 - 1/n)^n = e^-1

it does then tend towards poisson, since poisson is the infinite limit of binomial

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to arrange $n$ blank spaces on the board is $\binom{64}{n}$.  Given that every non-blank space has at least one cricket on, the number of distinct ways of then distributing the $n$ spare crickets among the remaining $64-n$ spaces is given by $\binom{64-n}{n}$

If $n$ is the number of empty squares and $f(n)$ enumerates the number of distinct ways of achieving $n$ then we have:

$$f(n)=\binom{64}{n}\times \binom{64-n}{n}$$

The expected value is given by $$\frac{\sum_{}f\times n}{\sum f}$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{63} n\times\binom{64}{64-n}\times \binom{64-n}{n}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{63} \binom{64}{64-n}\times \binom{64-n}{n}}$$

$$=\frac{1481084144392088988865778942592}{69699678772087924716181154417}≈21.2495$$

And the generalisation you requested for a board of $k$ squares is given by:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1} n\times\binom{k}{k-n}\times \binom{k-n}{n}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{k-n}\times \binom{k-n}{n}}$$

This can be generalised further to the case $m\neq k$ where $m$ is the number of crickets, but that is a little more complicated.

Furthermore, this answer makes the assumption not stated in the question that sufficient time has passed for every cricket to have jumped at least once.  If that has not happened then the answer is not calculable without more information but some estimation of the mean time before jumping would be sufficient to build a distribution of the rate at which the expected value of 21.249 would be approached and this would occur in accordance with a Poisson distribution.

Comment: This is not correct.  You can't just assign one cricket to each non-empty square and then distribute the rest.  If we do it for three squares, the chances are $\frac 3{27}$ that there are two empty, $\frac {18}{27}$ that there is one, $\frac {6}{27}$ of zero, giving an expectation of $\frac {24}{27}$.  The chance each square is vacant is $\frac 8{27}$.  Your calculation would be $\frac {0 \cdot 1 \cdot 1+1\cdot 3 \cdot 2+2 \cdot 3 \cdot 0}{1 \cdot 1+3 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 0}=\frac 67$

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't yet question that your critique is correct, but a critique of my answer will either be of the form that a) I have not enumerated the number of distinct combinations correctly, or b) all combinations are not equally likely.  Which of these does yours translate into, is it the lattter?  If so, and if you are correct this can be solved by numbering the crickets and enumerating the permutations instead of combinations.

Comment: You are not counting the arrangements correctly.  The denominator I show for $n=3$ says you find there are seven arrangements, that you cannot have two vacant squares, and that the chance of all squares occupied is $\frac 16$.  In fact the chance of all squares occupied is $\frac 6{27}$

Comment: @RossMillikan ok i've had a chance to look at your example of 3, and remember the question is to calculate the expected number of blank squares.  Nowhere do I state the probability of all squares occupied. The squares can be populated 300,210,201,111,120,102,012,021,030,003. The total number of blank squares is 12 out of 10 scenarios, giving an expected number of blanks equal to $\frac{12}{10}$. If we extend that to permutations instead, there are 6 ways of arriving at 300, 2 ways of arriving at 210 etc., we get an expectation of $\frac{49}{31}$, neither of which is your answer.

Comment: But 300 is only $\frac 16$ the chance of 111.  You denominator should be the total number of ways to distribute the crickets and the $n=0$ term of the sum should be the number of ways to fill all the squares.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, that's what I said about permutations. It's case b) the combinations are not equally likely and my answer needs adjusting to measure the varying likelihoods of each combination.  Have you an aswer yet to my question above of the non-zero probability of every square being blank? If you've considered this I can abandon my answer altogether but if you haven't then I'll redo my answer to correct it.

Comment: The binomial model just gives you the chance that one specific square is empty based on each cricket not being there.  It would not be correct to use that probability in a binomial model for the chance that some other number of squares is empty.  Your point that not all squares can be empty speaks directly to that, and the cause is the correlation between one square being empty and another.  It is still correct to multiply up the chance that one square is empty to get the expected number of empty squares, but we haven't learned any more about the distribution of the number of empty squares.

Comment: @RossMillikan ok i'll make my answer exact later and they should correspond then.  P.S. This problem is how many ways are there to partition the number 64 into between 1 and 64 parts. And across the entire set of partitions, what is the average of $64-p$ where $p$ is the number of partitions.